# Crystal reports converting a date into number

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to get the working days for employees per month. I am trying to convert the from date and to date into a numeric value only containing the day value. I know of the formula tonumber(totext(currentdate,'dd')) however it is not printing the requested output.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine as following:

[image]

Comment: i am sorry but there seems to be a misunderstanding, i need to calculate the number of days the employee has worked this month not the current day

Comment: @michelassi - Sorry for misunderstanding. Can you please show me your sql query?

Comment: sorry for the late reply work is crazy here is my sql quary:local NumberVar i;

Weeks := (Truncate ({Command.toDate} - dayofWeek({Command.toDate}) + 1 - ({Command.fromDate} - dayofWeek    ({Command.fromDate}) + 1)) /7 ) * 5;

Days := DayOfWeek({Command.toDate}) - DayOfWeek({Command.fromDate}) + 1 + 
(if DayOfWeek({Command.fromDate}) = crSunday then -1 else 0) + 
(if DayOfWeek({Command.toDate}) = crSaturday then -1 else 0);

Comment: //for iYear := Year({HEM1.fromDate}) to Year({HEM1.toDate}) do (
   // Local DateVar Array Holidays := getHolidays(iYear);
    //for i := 1 to uBound(Holidays) do (
      //  local NumberVar hMonth := Month(Holidays[i]);
       // local NumberVar hDay := Day(Holidays[i]);
        //local DateVar hDate := cDate(iYear, hMonth, hDay);
        //if DayOfWeek(hDate) in crMonday to crFriday and
          //  hDate in {HEM1.fromDate} to {HEM1.toDate} then Hol := Hol+1;